# How to create dynamic tabs from another activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, tabs

I have a method in Test1Activity that creates tabs inside a TabHost, but if I want have Test2Activity call the method, and I have to set the newTab method to static, I can't use Intent because it utilizes "this" to set the class.

```
public class Test1Activity extends TabActivity {
    public static void newTab(String tabIdentifier) {
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Reusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ChatActivity.class);
        spec = Test1Activity.tabHost.newTabSpec(tabIdentifier).setIndicator(tabIdentifier, null).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
        modifyTabSize();
    }
}

public class Test1Activity extends TabActivity {
    Test1Activity.newTab("Joe");
}
```

How do I fix this so that it would work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of tricks to using a static `Context`. One thing I have done occasionally is create a static Context and initialize it in `onCreate`. For example:

```
public class Example extends Activity {
    public static Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = this;
    }
}
```

Then, when you construct a new `Intent` object, use `context` instead of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Why would an activity do this? You should consider using a service/broadcastreciever combination so that the activity can update. Activity to activity can be done if you pass in information **DIRECTLY**.